# Turn file of 3 columns into a matrix

Tags: bash, shell, matrix, awk

I have a file with information separated into 3 columns. The first column represents the categories that will fill the top row of the matrix, the second column represents the categories that will be in the first column of the matrix. The third row represents the values that will fill the bulk of the matrix. Columns 1 and 2 of the original file can be reversed, it doesn't make a difference.

The file looks like this

```
Category1   type1   +
Category1   type2   -
Category1   type3   +
Category2   type1   +
Category2   type2   +
Category2   type3   +
Category3   type1   +
Category3   type2   -
Category3   type3   -
```

I want to turn it into a matrix that looks like this

```
    Category1   Category2   Category3
type1   +   +   +
type2   -   +   -
type3   +   +   -
```

I'm thinking awk will probably do it, I just don't know how to make awk do this

Comment: Concerning the input data: Are the columns tab-separated or separated by spaces? How should it be concerning output?

Comment: @Scheff Everything is tab separated

Comment: Aha. I will send a solution soon. (It currently works with spaces for input separation and tabs for output separation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
           {col[$1]; row[$2]; val[$2,$1]=$3}
     END   {for(c in col) printf "%s", OFS c; print "";
            for(r in row)
              {printf "%s", r;
               for(c in col) printf "%s", OFS val[r,c]
               print ""}}' file

         Category1       Category2       Category3
 type1   +       +       +
 type2   -       +       -
 type3   +       +       -
```

Comment: I think this is at the point where it would be better to put it into a script, rather than a "one liner".

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution based on GNU awk. I emphasize this because multi-dimensional arrays (which are obtained for a convenient solution) are a feature specific to GNU awk.

My script `table2matrix.awk`:

```
# collect values
{
  # category=$1 ; type=$2 ; value=$3
  if (!($1 in categories)) { categories[$1] }
  types[$2][$1] = $3
}
# output of values
END {
  # print col. header
  for (category in categories) { printf("\t%s", category); }
  print ""
  # print rows
  for (type in types) {
    printf("%s", type);
    for (category in categories) {
      printf("\t%s", types[type][category]);
    }
    print ""
  }
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ cat >table.txt <<EOF
> Category1   type1   +
> Category1   type2   -
> Category1   type3   +
> Category2   type1   +
> Category2   type2   +
> Category2   type3   +
> Category3   type1   +
> Category3   type2   -
> Category3   type3   -
> EOF

$ awk -f table2matrix.awk table.txt
        Category1       Category2       Category3
type1   +       +       +
type2   -       +       -
type3   +       +       -

$ cat table.txt | sed $'s/   /\t/g' >table-tabs.txt

$ awk -f table2matrix.awk table-tabs.txt 
        Category1       Category2       Category3
type1   +       +       +
type2   -       +       -
type3   +       +       -

$ cat >table-sorted.txt <<EOF
> Category1   type1   +
> Category1   type3   +
> Category2   type1   +
> Category2   type2   +
> Category2   type3   +
> Category3   type1   +
> Category1   type2   -
> Category3   type2   -
> Category3   type3   -
> EOF

$ awk -f table2matrix.awk table-sorted.txt 
        Category1       Category2       Category3
type1   +       +       +
type2   -       +       -
type3   +       +       -

$ tac table.txt >table-reverse.txt

$ awk -f table2matrix.awk table-reverse.txt 
        Category1       Category2       Category3
type1   +       +       +
type2   -       +       -
type3   +       +       -

$ grep '+' table.txt >table-incompl.txt

$ awk -f table2matrix.awk table-incompl.txt 
        Category1       Category2       Category3
type1   +       +       +
type2           +
type3   +       +

$
```

`table.txt` is space separated (copy/paste from Web browser), `table-tabs.txt` is `table.txt` with sequences of spaces replaced by tabs.

As obvious from script (but not from code sample in Web browser) the output is tab-separated.

After testing some variations of the original sample input, I fixed my awk script. It became a little bit shorter and much more similar to the other solution of [karafka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa)...